# Boas práticas com contract do bd Android

Tags: android

Quais seriam as boas práticas em relação ao sqlite no Android?
Eu uso um único db contract para todas tabelas (cada tabela uma classe dentro da classe principal contract)?

```
public final class FeedReaderContract {
    // To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
    // make the constructor private.
    private FeedReaderContract() {}

    /* Inner class that defines the table contents */
    public static class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "entry";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE = "subtitle";
    }

    public static class OutraTabela implements BaseColumns {
     ....
    }
}
```

Ou eu crio uma classe contract para cada tabela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma como você está fazendo está ótimo. Acredito que você também deve implementar um ContentProvider, então especificar as URI's de acesso para cada tabela no Contract é uma boa.

No mais, você só precisa de um arquivo de Contract. Se você tiver muitas tabelas mesmo, talvez possa separá-las em vários arquivos, agrupando as tabelas por assunto.

Esse treinamento da Google dá ótimos direcionamentos sobre o assunto:

https://br.udacity.com/course/android-basics-data-storage--ud845/

Comment: no caso eu tenho 12 tabelas (o que são muitas), eu fiquei confuso, pois nas documentações do google, não informa se eu devo colocar todas tabelas na mesma classe contract, eu pensei nisso pois.. São 12 tabelas, ou seja, 12 arquivos, não ficaria bagunçado?

Comment: Não existe um direcionamento pra isso na prática. 12 tabelas é pouco, até porque você só está criando constantes nas classes e alguns poucos métodos. Eu colocaria tudo numa só. Mas é a gosto do freguês, rs, o importante também é não "organizar" demais e dificultar a leitura.